# What is wrong with this docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I am trying to install gitlab ce with docker compose file. I have had lots of permissions problem with bind volumes. I would like to try names volumes. Following is my file.

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  container_name: 'gitlab'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.xxxx.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.xxxx.com'
  ports:
    - '10080:80'
    - '10443:443'
    - '10022:22'
  volumes:
    - gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
    - gitlab_log:/var/log/gitlab
    - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
volumes: 
  gitlab_config:
    external: true
  gitlab_log: 
    external: true
  gitlab_data:
    external: true
```

I receive following error:

```
docker-compose up -d
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'gitlab_data'
```

Volumes have been created previously with `docker volume create` command

UPDATE : Based the solution by Ganesh Satpute, I submit the working/tested file below. Someone may need it since gitlab page does not provide it. Thank you "Ganesh".

```
---
version: "2.4"
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    container_name: 'gitlab'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.xxxx.com'
    environment:
       GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: 'https://gitlab.xxxx.com'
    ports:
      - '10080:80'
      - '10443:443'
      - '10022:22'
    volumes:
      - gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
      - gitlab_log:/var/log/gitlab
      - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
volumes: 
  gitlab_config:
    external: true
  gitlab_log:
    external: true
  gitlab_data:
    external: true
```

Comment: which version of docker-compose are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your `docker-compose.yml` with this

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    container_name: 'gitlab'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.xxxx.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: 'https://gitlab.xxxx.com'
    ports:
    - '10080:80'
    - '10443:443'
    - '10022:22'
    volumes:
    - gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
    - gitlab_log:/var/log/gitlab
    - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
volumes:
  gitlab_config:
    external: true
  gitlab_log:
    external: true
  gitlab_data:
    external: true
```

Comment: What did you change?  Why does it help?

Comment: Why? Is it not working? I added docker-compose version and missing services tag.

Answer (score -2):

You can always check by running docker-compose config to check if the config file is valid or not. If not google the errors and also check few examples online.